# Make API get request and store response data into sql db

Tags: sql, node.js

I'm trying to make an API get request using node.js and take the returned json data and store one integer into a sql database. I want to overwrite and update existing data that is already in the db.

Essentially this api is returning funding data on presidential candidates and I want to return this data and write to a sql database.

Comment: Can you show what your code does currently?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and edit your question accordingly. What you have written gives us no chance to help you.